devcontainers: explanation of java semantic versioning for automatic updates
I'm fairly new to microsoft's/vscode's devcontainers. I'm setting up a new java dev environment. I'm referencing one of the pre-built versions of Dockerfile: mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/java:1-21. Everything works, but I was confused as to what the tag 1-21 meant. According to the docs it has something to do with automatic updates using semantic versioning.
According to the list of available tags, here is a sample of java 21 tags that are available:

1-21
1.1-21
1.1.0-21
1.1.1-21
1.1.9-21

Could someone help explain to me the differences between the various tags?

The number to the right dash is clearly the java version. The number to the left of the dash appears to be a semantic version number for a particular build of that java version. It appears they do this, and not something simpler like 21.1.9 for two reasons:

To distinguish between pre-release versions (0.*.*) and post release versions (1.*.*).
There was a release in Java 8 that Microsoft considers a major version update, leading to a 2.0.0-8.

Tags with missing minor and patch version numbers mean the latest such numbers. The tag will move as new minor/patch builds are released.

So does that mean:

For 1-21, if any 1.x.x comes out it will automatically get updated, but if a 2.x.x gets released, it would not updated?
For 1.1-21, if any 1.1.x comes out it will automatically get updated, but if a 1.2.x gets released, it would not get updated.
For 1.1.9-21, this wouldn't do any auto updates. It essentially pins it specifically to that particular version.


@james.lorenzen That is indeed how I would interpret the numbers.
